# Proof of $\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{m}U_j\right)\leq \sum_{j=1}^{m}\dim\left(U_j\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Is the following proof correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $U_1,U_2,...,U_m$ are finite dimensional subspaces of $V$. Prove that $$\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{m}U_j\right)\leq \sum_{j=1}^{m}\dim\left(U_j\right)$$

**Proof.** We prove the result by recourse to *Mathematical Induction*.

*Basis-Step:* For $m=2$ we know that $\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)-\dim(U_1\cap U_1)$.
evidently $\dim(U_1\cap U_1)\ge0$ consequently $$\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)-\dim(U_1\cap U_1)\le \dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)$$

*Inductive-Step:* Assume for an arbitrary $k\in\{2,3,4,...m\}$ that
$$\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}U_j\right)\leq \sum_{j=1}^{k}\dim\left(U_j\right)$$
thus $$\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}U_j\right)=\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}U_j+U_{k+1}\right)$$
$$\leq\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}U_j\right)+\dim\left(U_{k+1}\right)-\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}U_j\cap U_{k+1}\right)$$
similarly as in the base case
$$\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}U_j\cap U_{k+1}\right)\ge0$$
consequently 
$$\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}U_j\right)+\dim\left(U_{k+1}\right)-\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}U_j\cap U_{k+1}\right)\leq \dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}U_j\right)+\dim\left(U_{k+1}\right)$$
therefore 
$$\dim\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}U_j\right)\leq \sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\dim\left(U_j\right)$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks pretty good. There are a few minor changes I would make.

Instead of saying suppose it holds for arbitrary $k \in \{2,\dots,m\}$, you should assume it holds for some $k \geq 2$.

The other thing is a minor notational note. When you write $$ \sum_{j=1}^k U_j \cap U_{k+1}$$

it could be interpreted as $$\sum_{j=1}^k (U_j \cap U_{k+1}).$$

This is NOT the same as $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^k U_j\right) \cap U_{k+1}$$

which is what you meant. I would recommend using the parentheses to make sure you cannot be misinterpreted.